# Running 2 projects - one within another and debugging the 2nd

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2012, projects

I have a project that calls the `exe` of the other but, I want to be able to step through both projects calling from the parent project to the child project.

I'm running **VS 2012** with **C#**.  I can open my parent project and add my 2nd solution.  I can set either one as the start up project.  The 1st project calls the exe of the child currently.  So, somehow, I need it to call the project so I can debug it.

How do I do that?

```
Console.WriteLine("Setting up the StartInfo object for the ReportRunner.exe process run"); 
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(); 
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Documents\Dev\C#\ReportRunnerXLSX\ReportRunner\bin\Release\PortalReportRunner.exe"; 
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true; 
startInfo.Arguments = argies.ToString(); 
using (Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo)) 
{ 
      proc.WaitForExit(); 
}
```

Comment: I added it to the original post

Comment: Sorry, I have to ask: why do you even have to invoke the second project like this? Can't you just have a hard reference to it?

Comment: I don't know...I didn't write the original code and I'm not an expert C# developer.  What other way is there to call the exe?  Hard Reference?

Comment: You should have both projects in the same solution and add the second project as a project reference to the first one. This way you will be able to access any public types of the latter via code, *and* you will be able to debug easily.

Comment: Do I need to compile the 2nd project differently?  I can add another project to the solution but when I 'Add Reference' under Solution/Projects, it doesn't see the project file.

Comment: Do you still need that second project as an independant executable? If not make your project a class library.

Comment: I'll try that.  Not really. It was just originally developed that way.Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

If possible, turn that second project into a class library and add it as a project reference to the first project. This will allow you to debug *and* won't require a second process running. Don't forget to expose the required functionality as public types and members.

If you still need a second, independant executable, then just create a new executable library that will also refer to the newly converted class library. This will be much cleaner this way.